# Won't the new nonblocking architecture for /dev/random make it less secure?

Tags: linux, random, cryptography

If entropy is not accounted for, and the pool doesn't block even if insufficient entropy has been supplied, isn't it potentially insecure?

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/random` isn’t being made non-blocking by removing the need for entropy. In fact, it’s not really being made non-blocking; it’s become effectively “blocking for a short time at most” on most architectures, thanks to [the use of CPU execution jitter as a source of entropy](https://lwn.net/Articles/642166/).

What has been removed is [the blocking pool](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/) ([this is the commit that was merged](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=90ea1c6436d26e62496616fb5891e00819ff4849)). That was possible because the kernel’s cryptographic random number generator is considered good enough, once initialised, to not *require* additional entropy. It can still block, on initialisation, but on architectures with CPU execution jitter, that doesn’t last long.

All this means that [there’s no longer any meaningful difference between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`](https://lwn.net/Articles/884875/), so they could be merged. That change [has been submitted](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220217162848.303601-1-Jason@zx2c4.com/) but not merged so far.